# Using git with rails at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I would like to make a simple document editor using a rails app but I want it to have version history.  The best way I can see to do this would be to use git, but I can't find any information about using Git inside of a rails app!  When I search for git/rails (or any combination), I receive an overload of information about committing your projects, installing git and using it as a developer.  What I am trying to find, is how to use it INSIDE of the rails app, so the user using the webpage can edit a document and save changes with history - like Github's file editor.

Any ideas on how to find this?  Do you see any potential problems with this idea?  I'm not sure if git is meant just for the local development machine or if it could be used in production with concurrent users accessing - please help!

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/libgit2/rugged ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use system calls directly and take responsability for organizing your repositories.

Just use the `system` method or surround your call with `` (Ex: `ls`)